# Copying files from Local Dir to Server using webapp?

Tags: php, server, web-applications, dockerfile, uppy

I am building a webapp that requires users to upload the file directories from their local machine. The webapp is deployed from a remote server via Docker.
The way it works is like this:
From my local machine, I ssh into the server; from server I build the docker and run it.

Now, whenever somebody log in, they should be able to upload the whole directory from their local machine, while keeping the relative path of the files of the uploaded dir. What are some of the possible ways to do this?

I have tried UPPY but I can only upload individual files, and not the whole directory.

Also, I cannot mount the volumes because the docker is deployed from the server, and not my local machine.

Comment: How do they upload? UPPY?

Comment: Do they upload using your webapp? FTP ?

Comment: Yes, I am using UPPY on the frontend to upload the files. The individual files work but the uploading the whole directory doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what uppy is. is this a javascript package? ftp software like winscp/filezilla?